# Upper bound of the expectation of absolute value of a random variable

Tags: inequality, expected-value

For a non-negative random variable X, I am trying to show that $E(|X|+|E(X)|)^3 \le 8E|X|^3$, which I think is correct.

I am thinking,
$$
 E(|X|+|E(X)|)^3 \le E(2 \times max\{|X|,|E(X)|\})^3 \le 8 \times E(max\{|X|,|E(X)|\})^3 
$$
But I cannot see how it follows that the last term is bounded by $8\times E(|X|^3)$. Perhaps there is another way.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation is quite ambiguous regarding the order of the ^3 and the expectation... So, for further discussion it may be helpful, if you clarify that (e.g. with addidional and consitent brackets)

Besides that: If $X$ is a random variable s.t. $P(X=0)=1/2$ and $P(X=1)=1/2$, then $Y:= max(|X|,|E(X)|)$ has the distribution $P(Y=1/2)=1/2$ and $P(Y=1)=1/2$. (Because $X(\omega)=0 \implies Y(\omega)=1/2$ and $X(\omega)=1 \implies Y(\omega)=1$).

Hence, $E(X) < E(Y)$ and $E(|X|^3) < E(|Y|^3)$, so this seems to be a problem for you proof.

**Proof with a worse constant:**

For $x,y \ge 0$ we have
$$(x+y)^3 \le 8 max(x,y)^3 = 8 max(x^3,y^3) \le 8(x^3 + y^3).$$
Hence, for any constant $c$:
$$E[(|X|+c)^3] \le E[8(|X|^3+c^3)] = 8 E[|X|^3] + 8c^3$$
In particular for $c=E|X|$, we have
$$E(|X|+|E(X)|)^3 \le 8 E[|X|^3] + 8(E|X|)^3.$$
By Jensen's inequality applied to the convex function $f(x)=|x|^3$ we have $ (E|X|)^3 \le E[|X|^3]$, which concludes
$$E(|X|+|E(X)|)^3 \le 16 E[|X|^3]. $$

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I have fixed the parenthesis.  An alternative approach might be to consider $ E(|X|+|E(X)|)^3= E|X|^3 +3 (E|X|^2)(|E(X)|)+3 (E|X|)(|E(X)|)^2+(|E(X)|)^3$, and show that each term is bounded by E(|X|^3), although, I don't know how to.

Comment: So, the ^3 is always within the expectation? And is the 8 important to you -- or is any constant ok?

Comment: Yes, ^3 within expectation, i.e., I am computing the third moment of the sum.  Actually, nothing special about 8, any constant is fine.  But I think the bound should work with 8.

Comment: I think that this probably works with 8 as well, but I have only a proof with 16. I've added it above

Comment: Thank you so much!  This will be just fine for my work.  However, I have been thinking about this bit more and made some progress from the cubic expansion.  The second term $E(|X|^2 (|E(X)|) \le E(|X|^2 E(|X|) $.  Now $Cov(|X|^2, |X|)=E(|X|^3) -E(|X|^2E(|X|) $.   But, the covariance here is nonnegative, which implies $E|X|^3 \ge  E(|X|^2E(|X|)$.   I think the same argument holds for other terms. So, collecting the coefficients, we get 8.